# Connecting to H2 from Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, h2, connect

I'm trying to create a small desktop application in Java (Netbeans) that distributes with a database attached to it (Something similar to an old VB6 application with an mdb file for storing data).

I've created the project and put H2-1.4.190.jar in my project file. I can see the H2*.jar file from Netbeans, right under my main class.

I downloaded SQL Workbench, created a table (named 'Company') and put in a single row of data.

Now I need to (somehow) connect to the database and extract the data from Netbeans. Google hasn't been very helpful with this. How do I connect? How do I retrieve (or insert/edit) data? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connecting to H2 database in your netbeans project is essentially the same as connecting to any other database with a JDBC driver and with any other IDE. You put the jar file with the driver in your project and then use jdbc functions to access the database or use higher-level API's that call the jdbc functions indirectly.  Netbeans can also connect on its own to the database allowing you to use netbeans as an alternative the SQL Workbench for creating/viewing/editing tables.

To use inside your project:

1. Download the jar file: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/1.4.190/h2-1.4.190.jar
2. Select the libraries folder under your project in the Projects window.
3. Right-click for pop-up menu.
4. Select `Add Jar/Folder ...`
5. Select the jar you Downloaded.
6. Write code to access the database.

The following example reads from a database file in `/home/username/h2test.db` from a table named `UNTITLED` with two columns `time` and `description`.

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:/home/username/h2test")) {
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from UNTITLED");
    try(ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        while(rs.next()) {
            Date d = rs.getDate("time");
            String description = rs.getString("description");
            System.out.println(d+", " + description);
        }
    }
}
```

Only the `Class.forName("org.h2.Driver")` and the exact form of the url `jdbc:h2:/home/username/h2test` are specific to H2. The rest would work just the same with MySQL, SQLLITE, PostgreSQL, Derby etc.

There is a tutorial on JDBC  at :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

If you want to use Netbeans directly to edit/view tables without writing a program.

1. Open the Services window with Window -> Services.
2. Right-click Databases to choose `New Connection ...` from pop-up menu.
3. In the drop-down list on the first dialog for driver select `New Driver`
4. Add the h2-1.4.190.jar file to the Driver Files and click Next.
5. Edit the URL on the next dialog to replace your `<FILE>` with your file.
6. Click Finish.
7. A new connection node in the Services Window should be available. Right-click it and choose connect.
8. Expand the nodes to get to the Tables folder. Either use Create Table to create a new table or select an existing table and choose View Data.

Comment: That is, by far, the most complete answer I've gotten on SO! Thanks!